# How to check every div block for image

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check every block for image, and if it is empty, load image inside.

My try:

```
    function showFile(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var a = 1;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) continue;
      var fr = new FileReader();

      fr.onload = (function(theFile) {

        return function(e) {

            $('.tra').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.find('img').length === 0 ) {
        $this.append('<img src="'+e.target.result+'">');    
    } else {
        alert("You can select only 5 images");
    }
});
        };
      })(f);

      fr.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('photo').addEventListener('change', showFile, false);
```

After upload image, i want to show this image:

html:

```
<div class="tra full_photo">
</div>
 <div class="tra mini_photo">
              <div class="tra block_mini_photo block_mini_photo2"></div>
              <div class="tra block_mini_photo block_mini_photo3"></div>
              <div class="tra block_mini_photo block_mini_photo4"></div>
              <div class="tra block_mini_photo block_mini_photo5"></div>
</div>
<form>
 <input type="file" name="photo[]" id="photo" class="upload_true" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" multiple>
</form>
```

But after loading, all the blocks are filled
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv7qy5qe/)

Comment: Why `tra.find('img').length <= 0` ? You meant `tra.find('img').length === 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shold do this:

```
return function(e) {

        var tra = $('.tra');
        var one = false;

        // test each single div
        tra.each(function(){
            if($(this).find('img').length <= 0 && !one){
              $(this).append('<img src="'+e.target.result+'">');
              one = true;
            }
        });

        if(!one){
            alert("You can select only 5 images");
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be as below. Check demo - https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/sv7qy5qe/6/.

```
$('.tra').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.find('img').length === 0 ) {
        $this.append('<img src="'+e.target.result+'">');    
    } else {
        alert("You can select only 5 images");
    }
});
```